# Replicating changes in Cluster Nodes

Tags: linux, cluster

What is the best possible way to keep the changes aligned on all cluster Nodes ?
for example - If a person creates a user or installs an RPM, and miss to install on other nodes ?

I can do it via shell scripts and monitoring tools. But there is a chance of missing stuff in it. Also what is the industry standard ?

Comment: People should not be "installing an RPM" on your cluster nodes. Further, people should not even have permissions to do so. All package installation and every other bit of configuration should be tightly controlled in a configuration management system, and applied consistently across all nodes in a repeatable, programmatic fashion.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: configuration management is how this is done. Any package installation or configuration change is implemented first in your configuration management, and then applied consistently across all cluster nodes.

Ansible is my tool of choice for this, but saltstack, chef, puppet, are some other viable options.